# I stopped /etc/init.d/networking, I can't log back in to my server to start it, what do I do?

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, login

I was editing the interfaces on my EC2 instance then I used this command to restart it: `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

It restarted fine, but it gave a notice saying that isn't the correct way to do it. So I googled around and landed on a ServerFault question asking what is the correct way, and the answer said...

```
/etc/init.d/networking stop
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

...and so the next time I edited it, I ran the first command. It took a little more than 5 minutes and the server timed out.

I can't log back in to my server because networking isn't running...

Please, what are my options?

Additional info: I'm running the EC2 in a VPC, I have 4 ip addresses on that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the API or Web console to restart that instance.

Comment: Hey EEAA, thank you soo much! Quick tangential question, what is `/mnt` used for? I've seen that it has a lot of space but Amazon empties the directory whenever I restart an instance.

Comment: /mnt is nothing but ephermal storage. When  you start an "instance-store" Amazon EC2 instance, you get a certain amount of ephemeral storage allocated and mounted automatically.

Answer (score 4):

In future, probably better to do this:

```
/etc/init.d/networking stop && /etc/init.d/networking start
```

Gets around the pesky "losing connection" problem.

Comment: Some common wisdom say that you should use `shutdown -r 5` while doing these sort of things. So if you screw up, you just have wait for 5 minutes. And if everything goes well, you just cancel the shutdown.

Comment: That's a good idea BatchyX, I'll remember that one too.

Comment: Looks like this has changed in the years since this answer. In Amazon Linux 2016.09, the script is /etc/init.d/network.

Answer (score 0):

```
#/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Before that kindly login to AWS console reboot the AMI.